# Transfer from View model object to controller function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem passing a data model object to a function in the controller.
My view looks like this:

```
    @model StudentsScraper.Models.Student
<tr>
    <td>@Html.RouteLink("Edytuj", new { controller = "Admin", action = "Edit", st = Model}) </td>
    <th>
        @if (File.Exists(string.Format("~/Upload/Data/{0}.jpg", @Model.StudentIndex)))
        {
            <img src="@string.Format("~/Upload/Data/{0}.jpg", @Model.StudentIndex)" class="rounded float-left" alt="@Model.StudentIndex" />
        }
        else
        {
            @Model.StudentIndex
        }
    </th>
    <td>@Model.Name</td>
    <td>@Model.Surname</td>
    <td>@Model.Gradute</td>
    <td>@Model.Degree</td>
    <td>@Model.EmailUniversity</td>
    <td>@Model.PersonalEmail</td>
    <td>@Model.DateOfBirth</td>
    <td>@Model.Phone</td>
    <td>@Model.University</td>
    <td>@Model.DepartmentName</td>
    <td>@Model.YearOfUniversityEntrance</td>
</tr>
```

My function in controller look like this:

```
        public ActionResult Edit(Student st)
        {
            return View("EditDaneView", st);
        }
```

After starting, only the empty object appears in the function parameter. So my question is how to pass the model from view to function in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the id of the student into the link:

```
<td>@Html.RouteLink("Edytuj", new { controller = "Admin", action = "Edit", id = Model.StudentIndex }) </td>
```

You also need to create another view `Edit.cshtml` that will be the actual edit form to which the `RouteLink` is pointing:

Edit.cshml:

```
@model StudentsScraper.Models.Student

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.StudentIndex) // send the id of the edited user back in a hidden field

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Surname)

    [... other fields]
}
```

Please note, the name of the view `Edit.cshtml` corresponds to the name of the action in the controller `Edit`. Also you might decorate the method `Edit` with `HttpPost` attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Student st)
```